# Negative color with area color fill and yAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Base chart:

```
type: 'area',
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q3x9psdz/19/ 
But when cross value is to big for curent chart - yAxis is expanding:

```
  plotOptions: {
            series: {
                threshold: 20,
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 50,
            crosshair: true,
        },
    yAxis: {
        plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            },
            {
                value: 20,
                color: 'coral',
                dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                width: 2,
            }
    ]}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q3x9psdz/14/

Workaround is to use spline or line:

```
    series: [{
            type: 'spline',
        name: 'Chart',
        data: [[1523195126000,1],[1523195426000,3],[1523195726000,1],[1523196026000,2],[1523196326000,6],[1523196626000,5],[1523196926000,2],[1523197226000,3],[1523197526000,1]],
        negativeColor: true,
        color: '#FF4040',
        shadow: true

    }]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q3x9psdz/23/

But on cros no area color:

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            threshold: 2.5,
        }
    },
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q3x9psdz/21/

Any solution to have color fille area and not expanding yAxis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [series.softThreshold](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bellcurve.softThreshold) to `true`.

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    threshold: 20,
    softThreshold: true
  }
},
```

live example: https://jsfiddle.net/j58bvw36/